# Python - SSL Issue with Oauth2

Tags: python, ssl, oauth, certificate, ssl-certificate

I seem to be having an issue with SSL whenever trying to use oAuth2 in Python. I've spent most of the afternoon attempting to debug it but can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my Python Script (Nice and simple):

```
import oauth2.oauth2 as oauth
import urlparse
import time

## If you're actually processing requests, you'll want this
# import simplejson


### GET A REQUEST TOKEN ###

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="***KEYHERE***", secret="***KEYSECRETHERE***")

request_token_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'

client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")

request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))


token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
```

And these error from the Python Interpreter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\oAuth2Test\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
  File "E:\Projects\oAuth2Test\oauth2\oauth2.py", line 682, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "E:\Projects\oAuth2Test\httplib2\httplib2.py", line 1445, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "E:\Projects\oAuth2Test\httplib2\httplib2.py", line 1197, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "E:\Projects\oAuth2Test\httplib2\httplib2.py", line 1133, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "E:\Projects\oAuth2Test\httplib2\httplib2.py", line 914, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Now, just so it's known, I have my cacerts.txt that came with httplib2 in the proper place and it is found, yet I still have this problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cacerts.txt` contains too few CAs. If you replace it with [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) then there is no ssl error. Here's a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import http.client
import ssl

####context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='cacerts.txt') # ssl.SSLError
####context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='cacert.pem')  # works   
context = ssl.create_default_context()  # works as is on the recent versions
#NOTE: ssl.CERT_REQUIRED is set for the default Purpose.SERVER_AUTH

h = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.instagram.com', 443, context=context)
h.request('POST', '/oauth/access_token')
resp = h.getresponse()
print(resp.status, resp.reason) # produce expected 400 http error
print(resp.headers)
print(resp.read())
```

As the example demonstrates, the default CA list might be enough on the recent software versions.

Comment: This `cacerts.pem` seems much more complete. Handy link.

Comment: As a quick hack you can also overwrite the cacerts.txt with the cacerts.pem above - the downside is that you need to make sure this is done in all your virtualenv's - so it's not really ideal.

Comment: @jfs how did you generate `cacert.pem` ?

Comment: @RakeshKotian: I’ve downloaded it from the curl (ubiquitous http client) web site  (look at the link)

Answer (score 7):

First, run `pip install certifi`.  Then set the client's ca_certs property, before making any requests:

```
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
client.ca_certs = certifi.where()
```

This was inspired by jterrace's suggestion to use `httplib2.Http.add_certificate`

Answer (score 2):

The default cacerts.txt that comes with httplib2 contains these certificates:

- Verisign/RSA Secure Server CA
- Thawte Personal Basic CA
- Thawte Personal Premium CA
- Thawte Personal Freemail CA
- Thawte Server CA
- Thawte Premium Server CA
- Equifax Secure CA
- Verisign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority
- Verisign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority
- Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
- Verisign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2
- Verisign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2
- Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2
- Verisign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2
- Verisign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
- Verisign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
- Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
- Verisign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
- Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA
- Equifax Secure eBusiness CA 1
- Equifax Secure eBusiness CA 2
- Thawte Time Stamping CA
- thawte Primary Root CA
- VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
- Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority
- Go Daddy Certification Authority Root Certificate Bundle

The instagram HTTPS certificate is signed by:

- GeoTrust Global CA

You will need to add the certificate to your cacerts.txt

Comment: I have found the certificate details, but how do I get oauth2 to read a different cacerts.txt?

Comment: The oauth2 ``Client`` object inherits from ``httplib2.Http``, so you should call its [add_certificate](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#httplib2.Http.add_certificate) method.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue with Flask-Social's OAuth call to Facebook. The easiest solution is to install [httplib2.ca_certs_locator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httplib2.ca_certs_locater/0.2.0) plug-in.

In httplib2.**init**.py, there is a check built-in for loading certificates from another source instead of the cacerts.txt file provided with the library:

```
try:
    # Users can optionally provide a module that tells us where the CA_CERTS
    # are located.
    import ca_certs_locater
    CA_CERTS = ca_certs_locater.get()
except ImportError:
    # Default CA certificates file bundled with httplib2.
    CA_CERTS = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )), "cacerts.txt")
```

Installing this plug-in fixed the problem for me with no code-changes/hack-a-rounds.

Comment: Note that earlier versions of httplib2 do not try to load from `ca_certs_locator`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error on my system (OSX Yosemite) which had an old version of Python 2.7 installed (2.7.1).

I upgraded Python to 2.7.10 which solved the problem.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/

The clue was in the following warning message which I saw while I was experimenting with different solutions:

"InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning"

Answer (score 0):

One more way to update your `cacerts.txt` file is to keep `httplib2` up to date. They occasionally update this file, so if you run into this problem, check if you're not using the latest version of the library and update it.