# Windows Live Login API SSL issue - Python

Tags: python, api, rest, ssl, windows-live

I'm writing a program to invite several Windows Live Contacts into a web application, all in Django 1.4. I'm experiencing the following problem.

I'm able to log the user in Windows Live using his account credentials through the Windows Live REST API by using this piece of code

```
def hotmail(request):
auth_params = { 
        'client_id': settings.HOTMAIL_KEY,
        'scope': 'wl.basic',
        'response_type': 'code',
        'redirect_uri': 'http://my_testing_comain/hotmail/process'
    }   
auth_url = settings.HOTMAIL_AUTH_URL % urllib.urlencode(auth_params)
return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)
```

Then, I receive an Authorization Code that I exchange for an Access Token (according to the OAuth Protocol) this is the piece of code I use to process the Windows Live's response:

```
def hotmail_process(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    parameters = { 
            'code': request.GET['code'],
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': 'http://my_testing_url/hotmail/process',
            'client_id': settings.HOTMAIL_KEY,
            'client_secret': settings.HOTMAIL_SECRET,
        }   
    response = urllib2.urlopen(settings.HOTMAIL_AUTH_URL % urllib.urlencode(parameters)).read()
    response = simplejson.loads(response)
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(settings.HOTMAIL_KEY, settings.HOTMAIL_SECRET)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer)
    contacts = client.request(settings.HOTMAIL_USER_FRIENDS_URI % response['access_token'])
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.loads(contacts))
return HttpResponse('Invalid request')
```

But I get the following error:

```
SSLHandshakeError at /hotmail/process/
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://my_testing_url/hotmail/process/?code=5330307c-664c-4d5b-27b3-a19a97bc8546
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: SSLHandshakeError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

and the following traceback:


Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://my_testing_url/hotmail/process/?code=5330307c-664c-4d5b-27b3-a19a97bc8546

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'contacts')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/networks/contacts/views.py" in hotmail_process
  26.         contacts = client.request(settings.HOTMAIL_USER_FRIENDS_URI % response['access_token'])
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2/__init__.py" in request
  682.             connection_type=connection_type)
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in request
  1544.                     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in _request
  1294.         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in _conn_request
  1230.                   conn.connect()
File "/home/user/virtenvs/israel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in connect
  1005.                     raise SSLHandshakeError(e)

Exception Type: SSLHandshakeError at /hotmail/process/
Exception Value: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

The thing is that, if I delete the line where I do the client.request() for this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.HOTMAIL_USER_FRIENDS_URI % response['access_token'])
```

I get the contacts in json format in my browser

So, apparently, my python oauth2 lib is missing some certificates (or that's what I think), so I tried this [Python - SSL Issue with Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270195/python-ssl-issue-with-oauth2) with no results. I also tried some libraries before I found out that they were deprecated. I've also tried to do it with the plain REST API call but I got a "FORBIDEN" response.

My oauth2 library works fine because I was able to implement the same functionality with GMail.

Any help or hint will be truly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where you able to resolve this problem. It would be great if you could share your solution. :-)

Comment: Nope, I haven't, I ended up doing a mini-howto on how to export your contacts in CSV from hotmail and yahoo and writing parsers for that

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
jcts = urlib2.urlopen(settings.HOTMAIL_USER_FRIENDS_URI % response['access_token'])
contacts = simplejson.loads(jcts)
```