# ca_certs_locater/__init__.py import error

Tags: python, api, ca, httplib2

I was trying to get authentication of my api.However,it always show the following import errors:

```
public_key=raw.input ('...')

secret_key=raw.input ('...')

client = upwork.Client(public_key, secret_key)
```

It is supposed to appear a url, however it shows that

```
" File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/upwork/client.py", line 118, in __init__
    ca_certs=ca_certs_locater.get(),

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ca_certs_locater/__init__.py", line 36, in get
    raise ImportError()"
```

I don't know what I should do about the ca_certs_locater

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Also following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270195/python-ssl-issue-with-oauth2 does not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Before instantiating the upwork client, modify the module's LINUX_PATH constant.

```
import upwork

# Set the certificate path within the module
upwork.ca_certs_locater.LINUX_PATH = '/path/to/my/cert.crt'
...
client = upwork.Client(public_key, secret_key, **credentials)
...
```

Comment: this one worked for me on windows, referencing the cacert.pem mentioned in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The solution is indeed as the comment suggests to do what [Python - SSL Issue with Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270195/python-ssl-issue-with-oauth2) says in combination with following the "SSL Certificate Note" on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-upwork. I did the following:

1. Read https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork/issues/9
2. Downloaded cacert.pem from [Python - SSL Issue with Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270195/python-ssl-issue-with-oauth2)
3. Set the HTTPLIB_CA_CERTS_PATH environment variable to /path/to/cacert.pem

Then, the import error went away. My use case was the upwork API and yours may be different but the solution is the same either way.