# ImportError in Python library

Tags: python, upwork-api

I am trying the [python-upwork library](https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork) and followed the setup. `pip freeze` shows required libraries:

```
httplib2==0.10.3
httplib2.system-ca-certs-locater==0.1.2
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
oauth2==1.5.211
urllib3==1.10
```

However trying to create client gives

```
client = upwork.Client(public_key, secret_key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/upwork/client.py", line 119, in __init__
    ca_certs=ca_certs_locater.get(),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ca_certs_locater/__init__.py", line 36, in get
    raise ImportError()
```

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270195/python-ssl-issue-with-oauth2) and it sounds like python cannot find the cert to validate upwork.com. I tried following suggestions but still same issue. I'm not sure where to put the cacerts.pem file.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Here is what worked for me. I am on Mac.

Download the latest pem file from link at bottom of [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SSL). Then force copy to specific location and rename it:

```
sudo cp cacert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Then it works!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options for this (based on this repo [python-upwork](https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork/blob/master/upwork/ca_certs_locater.py) :

1. if you are on linux move the ca-cert to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
2. if you are on osx move the ca-cert to `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`
3. if you want to use custom path, use variable env `UPWORK_SSL_CERT` and set the custom path value.

Comment: Options 1. and 2. seemed to be the only solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the env variable: `HTTPLIB_CA_CERTS_PATH` - it should solve the issue.

**Important** Make sure that you use `httplib2.system-ca-certs-locater 0.1.2` that supports HTTPLIB_CA_CERTS_PATH in compare to `httplib2-ca_certs_locater`. See recommendations here - https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork#ssl-certificates-note.

Comment: @ mnovozhylov, it seems to me that you are working for upwork:) I am a Ph.D. student and I am desperately looking for api access to upwork data for my research. I applied through researchrequests mail, but haven't heard for 3 weeks... Could you somehow help on this matter?

Comment: @edyvedy13, please, visit https://support.upwork.com and press "Get Help" button right after "Contact Upwork Customer Service" label. The Support Team will help you to handle the request and update with the details.

Comment: I have done that too, 10 days ago, they said they will let me know but still no reply